# Error running PostgreSQL query from SQL Server 2016

Tags: postgresql, syntax

The below query runs well in SQL Server 2016:

```
select ResellerId, vCompanyName ,x.* 
from wlt_tblReseller AS main 
outer apply ( select (count (ipkReportTypeId)) AS "count", vReportTypeName  
              from wlt_tblReseller _all 
              inner join wlt_tblClient clients  on clients.ifkParentResellerId = _all.ResellerId
              inner join wlt_tblReport_CompanyMaster reporslogs on reporslogs.ifkCompanyId = clients.ClientId
              inner join wlt_tblReports_TypeMaster rpt_types on rpt_types.ipkReportTypeId = reporslogs.ifkReportTypeId 
              where RootResellerId = main.ResellerId 
                and rpt_types.bStatus =1 
                and bIsStatic =1 
                and vReportTypeName  is not null
              group by ipkReportTypeId,vReportTypeName
            ) AS x 
WHERE IsMiniReseller = 0 
  and ResellerId <> 1  
  and vReportTypeName is not null 
order by  vCompanyName desc
```

But when I take it to PostgreSQL and change `OUTER APPLY` to `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`, it does not run and produces the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" LINE 9:    )AS x WHERE
> IsMiniReseller = 0 and ResellerId <> 1  and v...
> SQL state: 42601 Character: 649

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
select main.ResellerId, main.vCompanyName , x."count", x.vReportTypeName
from wlt_tblReseller AS main 
LEFT JOIN   ( select (count (ipkReportTypeId)) AS "count", vReportTypeName, RootResellerId  
              from wlt_tblReseller _all 
              inner join wlt_tblClient clients  on clients.ifkParentResellerId = _all.ResellerId
              inner join wlt_tblReport_CompanyMaster reporslogs on reporslogs.ifkCompanyId = clients.ClientId
              inner join wlt_tblReports_TypeMaster rpt_types on rpt_types.ipkReportTypeId = reporslogs.ifkReportTypeId 
              where 
                    rpt_types.bStatus =1 
                and bIsStatic =1 
                and vReportTypeName  is not null
              group by ipkReportTypeId,vReportTypeName
            ) AS x ON x.RootResellerId = main.ResellerId
WHERE IsMiniReseller = 0 
  and ResellerId <> 1  
  and vReportTypeName is not null 
order by  vCompanyName desc
```

PS. Add table aliases to all column names for to remove potential ambiguity...